# How can I query for embedded rows? Do I need Postgres JSON?

Tags: sql, database

In my application, a user can belong to many groups, and each group can have many members.

I want to issue a query that, based on a user ID, will return all the groups that user belongs to, *and* the list of members for each group. Something that would let me build a response like this:

```
{
    "user_id": 405,
    "user_name": "foobar",
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "Tomato Club",
            "members": [
                {
                    "user_id": 408,
                    "user_name": "barry"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": 410,
                    "user_name": "sarah"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to do this in only one query, or even if such a thing is possible. I'd really appreciate any tips about what to research.

Here's how my schema looks:

### users

```
id | name
---|-----
 1 | Dave
 2 | Laura
```

### groups

```
id | name
---|--------
 1 | Tomato Club
 2 | Watermelon Club
```

### groups_users_link

```
user_id | group_id
--------|----------
   1    |   2
   2    |   2
   5    |   1
   5    |   3
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty standard many-to-many relationship. You need three tables to represent this with standard SQL techniques. Using JSON is counter-productive.

Comment: Well I have three tables in that I have 'groups', 'users', and 'groups_users_link', I'm just not sure how I'd do a "select user, and all their groups, AND all the users for each group" query.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a minimal representation of that schema? Writing a query for that is usually as easy as doing a double `JOIN`.

Comment: @tadman I've updated the question to show my schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sort of relational structure makes it really easy to get all users in a group:

```
SELECT * FROM groups
  LEFT JOIN groups_users_link ON groups_users_link.group_id=groups.id
  LEFT JOIN users ON groups_users_link.user_id=users.id
```

You can add `WHERE groups.id=2` to narrow those results down to a single group.

[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e29e3f/2).

To do this all from the top with a single user in mind it gets a bit convoluted, but the same pattern applies:

```
SELECT * FROM users
  LEFT JOIN groups_users_link ON groups_users_link.user_id=users.id
  LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id=groups_users_link.group_id
  LEFT JOIN groups_users_link AS gul_sub ON gul_sub.group_id=groups.id
  LEFT JOIN users AS group_users ON gul_sub.user_id=group_users.id
  WHERE users.id=5 AND group_users.id!=users.id
```

Which you can [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e29e3f/6).

Comment: This gets all users in a group, but that's not what I'm after. I'm trying to get all of user *X*'s info, including all the groups they're in, and all the members of those groups. Getting all of a user's groups is easy, and all of a group's users, but how can I get a user's groups' users?

Comment: Can always chain it one step further. Edited accordingly.